# Fill holes in 3d mesh from image segmentation with CGAL or something else?

Tags: mesh, image-segmentation, cgal

I got some segmented image data from a CT scan of a body part in .raw file format. Segmentation was performed in Amira.
In CGAL, I created an .inr file, read this, then meshed this with certain mesh criteria:

```
typedef CGAL::Labeled_mesh_domain_3<K> Mesh_domain;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain,CGAL::Default,Concurrency_tag>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3t3;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;

(...)

Mesh_domain domain = Mesh_domain::create_labeled_image_mesh_domain(inr_image);
Mesh_criteria criteria(facet_angle=fangle, facet_size=fsize, facet_distance=fdist,
     cell_radius_edge_ratio=creratio, cell_size=csize);

C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria, lloyd());
```

I could create a 3d tetrahedral mesh (.vtu) with CGAL for finite element stuff which works fine.

**BUT:** Unfortunately the final mesh contains too much "holes" between the different tissue types and that's... very bad. So my question is: Is there a way to fill these holes with CGAL? I am open for other ways, too, because it won't be possible to segment the huge amount of data again (this was not done by me).

Thanks a lot, any help appreciated.

Comment: When you look at the segmented image, do you see those holes? Did you try to reduce the facet_distance to reduce the approximation error of the CGAL mesher?

Comment: @sloriot Yes, I can see the holes, some are bigger, some are smaller, they are from the poor segmentation. I wanted to "fill" these holes with the surrounding material. Reducing the facet_distance did not help. I just found another way to do this since it does not seem to be possible with CGAL. I read the segmented .raw data in matlab into a multidimensional array (according to the segmented slices) with `multibandread` and then programmed an algorithm that fills the holes, wrote it again into .raw format and meshed it with CGAL. Maybe not 100% exact, but the quickest way at the moment.

Comment: Some useful keyword to work on the image and fill the holes is ['closure'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)), but you need to use an image processing library.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did :-) I used matlab functions like `imclose()` and `imfill()` (together with some smoothing) which worked well!